# A question on gaussian measure in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a real separable Hilbert space. Suppose $\mu\sim N(0,S)$ on $H$, where $S$ is a positive, symmetric, of trace class operator on $H$. If $\lambda$ is a measure on $H$ with the Radon-Nikodym derivative 
>   $$\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}(x)=\exp[(c,x)-\frac{1}{2}(Sc,c)]$$
>   for some $c\in H$. Prove that $\lambda\sim N(Sc,S)$.

My attempt: I tried to calculate the characteristic function 
$$E_{\lambda}[e^{i(x,y)}]=\int_H e^{i(x,y)}\lambda(dx)=\int_H e^{i(x,y)}e^{(c,x)-\frac{1}{2}(Sc,c)}\mu(dx)$$
and then I was stuck there. I thought I should do some kind of change of variables and then use the property that $\mu$ is Gaussian. Could anyone give me some hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be $\lambda \sim N(c,S)$. I don't know what are you allowed to use here (because the fact itself is very standard), but probably you can compute the integral using that, with respect to $\mu$, $(y,x)$ and $(c,x)$ are jointly Gaussian with some characteristics (which you should know).

Comment: Why are the two functional jointly Gaussian? Is it by definition?

Comment: In a sense, yes. A vector is Gaussian iff all linear combinations of its components are Gaussian. The latter does hold here by definition.